# Use same label for 2 fields in crispy-forms

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I want to use the same label for more then one field in crispy forms. I want to know if I can do this, because I have tried many ways and none of them has worked.

```
self.fields[('field_1'),('field_2')].label = "Same Label:"

self.fields['field_1','field_2'].label = "Same Label:"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it as two separate lines (use a constant if you want to prevent repetition):

```
self.fields['field_1'].label = "Same Label:"
self.fields['field_2'].label = "Same Label:"
```

Or you can do it as a single line:

```
self.fields['field_1'].label = self.fields['field_2'].label = "Same Label:"
```

Note that this is really a question about Python, not Django or crispy forms. Inside the form's methods, `self.fields` is simply a Python dictionary. Therefore your attempts `self.fields[('field_1'),('field_2')]` and `self.fields['field_1','field_2']` is trying to access a key `('field_1', 'field_2')` from the dictionary, which will give an error because it doesn't exist.